# How do I get a barcode in Magento email template

Tags: magento, barcode

My shipping process involves typing the order number into UPS as part of the ShipWorks+UPS integration. Are there any barcode extensions that actually work? I've tried ones using CSS table styling but those never show up in the emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this out while scouring the net on my quest for all my other recent problems.

Zend has a built in barcode generation class, `Zend_Barcode`. Then googling php image output, I put together this little script I uploaded to `var/export/_barcode.php`:

```
<?php
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
if( isset($_GET['ord']) && strlen($_GET['ord']) > 5 ) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $_GET['ord']); 
    $rendererOptions = array(); 
    // Draw the barcode in a new image, 
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw( 
        'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions 
    ); 
    imagejpeg($imageResource);

} else { echo "<pre><b>Error:</b> required input not found\n"; }
?>
```

If you visit this script's URL with the standard GET, you'll be served a scannable barcode. So put this in your Transactional Email template:

```
<img src="http://yourmagentowebsite.com/var/export/_barcode.php?ord={{var order.increment_id}}" 
    alt="{{var order.increment_id}}" 
    style="margin-bottom:10px;" 
    border="0"/>
```

It's easy, and just plain works. When combined with something like Magemagician_Adminorderemail, you can make the template that you use internally for handling orders more compact and useful than the default order notification you send to customers.

Since our invoices are simple numbers, `code39` is ok. Be careful if you try to send it spaces or lowercase letters, as code 3 of 9 is very strict. I did not research other options in the `Zend_Barcode` class.